# Python Django 2.0 DecimalField "Ensure that there are no more than 3 digits before the decimal point"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.0

My amount column attributes are set to ***max_digits = 13, decimal_places = 7*** because you could technically have something like 10000.0000001 bitcoin.

When I try to enter and submit just 0.1 Bitcoin on my form I get the error:

> Ensure that there are no more than 3 digits before the decimal point.

This isn't working as expected: 0.1 is not more than 3 digits, and even if it was I should still be able to set more than 3 digits.. What is happening here?

models.py

```
class Transactions(models.Model):   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)  
    coin = models.CharField(max_length = 64)  
    buysell = models.CharField(default = 'buy', max_length = 4)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 13, decimal_places = 7)  
    trade_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
    trade_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

forms.py

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    CHOICES = ((1, 'Buy'), (2, 'Sell'),)

    coin = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Coin.objects.all()) 
    buysell = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)

    field_order = ['buysell', 'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price']

    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = {'buysell', 'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price'}
```

Comment: Try to pass your number like that: `number = round(0.1, 7)`.

Comment: Are you sure that the backend is getting `0.1`. Can you confirm the by checking the request data. It seems like there is something more being sent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say, `0.1` does not have more than 3 digits before the decimal point, so it should not give that error. Therefore the error is probably coming from a different field.

You haven't said what field is giving the error, or what values you submitted for other fields, but I suspect that the problem is your `trade_price` field.

```
trade_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
```

Currently, this supports a max value of `999.99`. Therefore if you entered `trade_price=10000`, you would get the `no more than 3 digits` error.

Answer (score 0):

Give the decimal value for `trade_price` like so:

```py
trade_price = "10000.0000001"
```

I beleive you have been doing it like this:

```py
trade_price = 10000.0000001
```

The quotation mark is the difference. PS 10000 is a heck ton of Bitcoin.